# ModBus TCP communication using Ruby: failing to implement HelloWorld

Tags: ruby, modbus-tcp

I am able to communicate with a ventilation installation ([Helios KWL EC 500 W](https://www.heliosventilatoren.de/mbv/kwl_modbus_easycontrols_82269-001_0917.pdf) which supports holding registers only, english description starts at 50% of the file) using the [modpoll](http://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html) utility v3.4. But I failed to transfer the very first communication to Ruby and the [rmodbus library](https://github.com/rmodbus/rmodbus) v1.3.3.

With modpoll, I may request some temperature value with the command

```
./modpoll -m tcp -a 180 <ipaddr> 0x7630 0x3031 0x3034 0x0000
```

and then read the data using

```
./modpoll -m tcp -a 180 -t4:hex -c 8 -0 -1 <ipaddr>
 Protocol configuration: MODBUS/TCP
 Slave configuration...: address = 180, start reference = 1 (PDU), count = 8
 Communication.........: x.x.x.x, port 502, t/o 2.00 s, poll rate 1000 ms
 Data type.............: 16-bit register (hex), output (holding) register table
 -- Polling slave...
 [1]: 0x7630
```

which outputs 8 16bit registers as stated as example in the Helios modbus documentation. As very first step, I tried to move the read part to Ruby. However, my Ruby code times out:

```
require 'rmodbus'
ModBus::TCPClient.new(ipaddr, 502) do |client|
  client.with_slave(1) do |slave|
    slave.debug = true
    puts slave.holding_registers[180..187]
  end
end
```

and throws the exception

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmodbus-1.3.3/lib/rmodbus/slave.rb:241:in `rescue in query': 
Timed out during read attempt (ModBus::Errors::ModBusTimeout)
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmodbus-1.3.3/lib/rmodbus/slave.rb:232:in `query'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmodbus-1.3.3/lib/rmodbus/slave.rb:164:in `read_holding_registers'
```

What's wrong?

I am not sure if / how to use the parameters output by modpoll "address =180" and "start reference =1". Is "address" equivalent to "holding register #"?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this one was rather stupid. For the records (and others who might want to talk to their Helios using rmodbus):

```
slave.debug = 1
```

turns on the debugging which outputs the byte stream sent to the modbus slave. The first bytes sequence is supposed to be: transaction number (2 byte), protocol specifier (2 byte, always zero), size of the following message (2 byte), unit identifier (1 byte, *always 180 for Helios KWL*).

The slave needs to be initialized with its unit identifier 180, instead of 1:

```
client.with_slave(180) do |slave|
```